# Vuetify v-select item slot not able to select

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I have this code:

```html
<v-select
  v-model="select"
  :items="countries"
  item-title="name"
  item-value="last"
  item-text="name"
  variant="solo"
>
  <template v-slot:selection="{ item }">
    <Icon :icon="item.raw.code"/>&nbsp; {{ item.raw.name }}
  </template>
</v-select>
```

That displays me this result [Bug - Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nki6W.png)

But the final result i want is this one, where icon is prepended to each item [wished result - Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68RBH.png)

I tried to use this code

```html
<template v-slot:item="{ item }">
  <Icon :icon="item.raw.code"/>&nbsp; {{ item.raw.name }}
</template>
```

but it broke all the mechanisms of selection

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

The answer is contained in the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#item):

> The item slot is used to change how items are rendered in the list. It provides `item`, an InternalItem object containing the transformed item-title and item-value; **and `props`, an object containing the props and events that would normally be bound to the list item.**

You are missing the `props` object that maintains the selection functionality for each item. Add it to your v-slot and bind it to your Icon element.

```html
<template v-slot:item="{ props, item }">
  <Icon v-bind="props" :icon="item.raw.code"/>&nbsp; {{ item.raw.name }}
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it's actually not working, im getting the same result as my version :/, Yeah alsoo, I saw the doc it's bit differents code im using Icon

Comment: The documentation code also works correctly. Why `<Icon>` doesn't work comes down to whatever `<Icon>` is, which you've not shown. It's not a native HTML element so I assume it's either custom to your project or from a library.  Not knowing what it is, I can't tell you how to make it work. If you can, you should use `<v-list-item>` to wrap whatever content must go in the item slot

Comment: [example code](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNptUk1vwyAM/SsWl2xSPiatpyqtNO2807RT0wNLqIZEAAHJKqH89xmSNHTbDb/3bD/bnDyxpq1etC7HgZE9qR3rtaCOHRsJUI8F1To+Y9Aq6SiXzCxQBC0TrHUrADAWveqYODRkYcjG7TnWt0i1apDOcGZTNpCF404wVEjasz/kSMUQyBY7pORIDafShZ5KqI25+USn62Ro0ArlohVM8KCN0jaPDWBqSJIT5xPcuiKSY/HJZYc5MaMhsHpNrcS2tdVUHjnuq67iE7wPJUpDv8sw2TTVVVI6TU89V3fnmKF14xvU8fHo/YyGwiFebobq+6MFZL7pXXEMbWu4dmCZG+aT814r48CDYReY4GJUDxl+kyzIAbCuDfLQFQ5B9PC44bcDL9RpNuQhTL+H7OM9y1HUhfdgM5jyX4JXKmlHN1FL/xG9sSsueRP111V0Ri+4+zgTTkOmnDyXu/KpoEJ/0XJH5nhHzj9DLeyl). You should be able to replace the `<span>` with your icon

Comment: Thanks a lot Yoduh - It's actually working when i wrap it with v-list-item 

Thank's a lot